# I need help navigating an odd JSON response

Tags: json

I have a call that is returning the following JSON response:

```
{resolved: false, rejected: false, errorHandled: false, handlers: Array(0)}
dispatching: false
errorHandled: false
handlers: []
rejected: false
resolved: true
value: {references: Array(2)}
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

I am struggling to work with the response. I am trying to navigate down to the value key but the console is returning it as undefined and will only return keys in the brackets on the first line.

Comment: That's **not** JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some more research, I believe I've found the real answer to this question. I've kept my original answer below the line, because it answers your question as written.

The response in your question appears to be a [Zalgo Promise](https://github.com/krakenjs/zalgo-promise) logged in the browser console. See my recreation below:
[image: A Zalgo Promise in the browser console]

Notice how `value` is undefined in the preview, but is defined once you expand the preview into a full object (and how "resolved" goes from false to true). This is because the preview shows you the properties of the object when it's logged, but when you expand it, the expanded object shows you the properties of the object when it was manually expanded. This means that the object's properties have changed between logging it to the console and expanding it in the console.

To be able to get the value of the response in your code, you'll have to wait until the Zalgo promise has resolved instead of trying to access its value immediately. If you're currently accessing the value like this:

```
var value = response.value;
//Do stuff with the value here
```

You can do this instead to wait for the value to be ready:

```
response.then(value => {
    //Do stuff with the value here
    //eg. console.log(value.references[0])
});
```

`response` in the code above should be whatever variable you passed into `console.log` to get the response for your question here.

If you have any questions, feel free to leave a comment below; getting this answer was a bit of a leap from your question.

---

Original answer (feel free to ignore, but technically answers your question as it's written):

That response isn't properly formatted as JSON. The solution here is likely to make sure that wherever you're getting this response from sends it as proper JSON in the first place.

If what you've put in the question is the response as a string, trying to reformat the current response to interpret it correctly won't work; you'll end up with duplicate keys that can have different values (`resolved`, `rejected`, `errorHandled`, and `handlers`), and you won't be able to access what's inside the `value` key at all.

Something noteworthy that might help you with debugging this: The response you're getting is very similar to what you'd see if you logged an object in the browser console. I've recreated something similar here:
[image: A recreation of the question's "JSON" response]

However, this does not explain the behavior in your question, where you can read some keys but only those displayed in the first line. I'm not sure what's going on there.